# Мусор при присваивании строк

Tags: c++, указатели, перегрузка-операторов

Есть класс в котором содержится размер строки и указатель на строку buf, определена функция set, определен конструктор копии и перегружен оператор присваивания.

```
Coder::Coder(const Coder& ob)
{
    m_buf = new char[ob.m_size];
    m_size = ob.m_size;
    strcpy(m_buf, ob.m_buf);
}
```

```
void Coder::set(const char* buf, int size)
{
    m_buf = new char ('\0');
    strcpy(m_buf, buf);
    if (!size || size != strlen(buf) + 1) throw std::logic_error("logic error");
    m_size = size;
};
```

```
Coder Coder::operator= (Coder& ob)
{
    if (ob.m_size > m_size)
    {
        delete[] m_buf;
        m_buf = new char[ob.m_size];
        m_size = ob.m_size;
    }
    
    strcpy(m_buf, ob.m_buf);
    
    return *this;
}
```

При выполнении следующих инструкций

```
Coder* pCoder = new Coder;
    pCoder->set(buf_hello, strlen(buf_hello) + 1);
    std::cout << "Coder pointer buf: "<<pCoder->buf() << std::endl;

    Coder coder;
    coder = *pCoder;

    std::cout << "coder buf: " << coder.buf() << std::endl;
```

В pCoder записывается Hello Global World!, а в coder - Hello Global Wor + мусор.
В чем проблема? Адреса разные, длина одинаковая.

Класс приведен ниже

```
class Coder
{
public:
    void set(const char* buf, int size);
    void set(int buf, int size);
    char* buf() const { return m_buf; }
    int size() const { return m_size; }

    Coder() : m_buf(0), m_size(0) {};

    Coder(const Coder& ob);
    
    Coder operator= (Coder& ob);
    
private:
     char* m_buf;
     int m_size;
};
```

Comment: И как вы в `set` в `память для одного символа копируете какую-то строку? Вот и все, приехали... Выход за пределы массива. UB.  Дальше можно и не копаться... Кстати, класс-то можно и полностью привести, откуда ж мы знаем, что у вас там...

Comment: так там мало что копируют, там ещё и старый буфер похоже того, утекает

Comment: pCoder->set(buf_hello, strlen(buf_hello) + 1);
тут set работает корректно.
Проблема появляется после присваивания *pCoder объекту coder

Comment: @Hipst0man ваш set() в любом случае работает некорректно, т.к. вызывает переполнение буфера. Результат непредсказуем и может вылезти где угодно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вобщем, так. Меняем только одно: ваш КОРРЕКТНО РАБОТАЮЩИЙ `set` (на утечку памяти плюнем).

```
void Coder::set(const char* buf, int size)
{
    if (!size || size != strlen(buf) + 1) throw std::logic_error("logic error");
    m_buf = new char[size];
    strcpy(m_buf, buf);
    m_size = size;
};
```

Скомпилируйте и проверьте - пропала ошибка В ДРУГОМ МЕСТЕ или нет?

Только учтите, что это все ваши проблемы не решает.

Comment: Проблема решена. А в чем она заключалась?
Получается я выделил память для 1 символа и пытался запихнуть целую строку?
В таком случае не могу понять почему один раз сработал set, а второй раз - нет.

Comment: Почему, когда кто-то перебегает на красный свет дорогу, его не каждый раз ведут на кладбище? Потому что это - **неопределенное поведение**. Один раз не повезет, и все сработает, вызывая ваше мнение "в `set` все отлично". В другой раз повезет, и программа просто крашится. На всякий случай - я именно так и хотел сказать - авария программы - это везение, потому что ошибка видна сразу. Невезение - если ошибка есть, а программа работает внешне корректно...

Comment: Спасибо за терпение и подробное объяснение)
Вылавливание таких ошибок приходит с опытом? Функция несколько раз сработала и я убил пол дня чтобы найти ошибку где-то в другом месте.

Comment: Да не знаю, наверное... Просто есть некоторые стандартные ошибки, которые делаются чаще всего. И с памятью - наиболее распространенные. Вот и смотришь в первую очередь на память - нет ли где неприятностей...

Comment: @Hipst0man замечу, что подавляющая часть ошибок обычно проявляет себя не в том месте, где реально были допущены. Так что привыкайте))

Answer (score 2):

Вижу следующую цепочку событий:

1)

```
pCoder->set(buf_hello, strlen(buf_hello) + 1);
```

Тут метод Set() вызывает переполнение буфера и записывает часть вашей строки в область, за пределами блока памяти, выделенного оператором new().

2)

```
std::cout << "Coder pointer buf: "<<pCoder->buf() << std::endl;
```

Тем не менее соответствующая строка пока цела, по-этому её вывод отрабатывает корректно.

3)

```
Coder coder;
    coder = *pCoder;
```

Перегруженный оператор присваивания перед тем, как скопировать строку, вызывает оператор new(), который выделяет новый блок памяти из свободной области, которая оказалась расположена следом за тем блоком, что был выделен предыдущим вызовом new(). А как мы помним, после предыдущего вызова new() у нас произошло переполнение буфера, и хвост строки оказался в свободной области. Новый оператор new() его и перезаписал, разместив в нём заголовок блока - вот вам и "мусорные символы".

Вывод: ошибка в методе set().